# Madelineproto stop all process (stop Eventhandler)

Tags: php, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I spend lots of time to discover how i should to stop Eventhandler process but it didn't work

this is my code:

```
<?PHP
self::$MadelineProto = new API('session.madeline', $settings);
self::$MadelineProto->startAndLoop(Events::class);
// self::$MadelineProto->stop(); not working 
// self::$MadelineProto->logout(); not working
// self::$MadelineProto->auth->logOut(); not working
```

I tried to stop eventhandler process (Madelineproto)